# Getting URL of Resized Image

Tags: theme-development, functions

I have a Wooframework specified question.
I'm using [Bueno](http://www.woothemes.com/2009/11/bueno/) theme with WooFramework 4.5.4 . I'm trying to get url of image which resized with **Dynamic Image resizer** of WooFramework on single.php. I'm using woo_get_image('image', 490, 200); for this but this isn't returning url of image, it's displaying image on page, directly. I need to get url. So i can use it like this : `<img src="<?php get_img_url(); ?>">` .

Which function should i use?

Comment: Sounds like a Woo Themes Support question.

Comment: Yes, because of this i said "I have a Wooframework specified question." .

Comment: Why not ask it in the Woo Themes Support Site?

Comment: They are wanting 70$ for forum support.

Comment: why not use WP's image_resize function ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to increased security risks with on-the-fly resizing scripts, I would convert over to  the_post_thumbnail() or get_the_post_thumbnail() functions. If your theme doesn't have post-thumbnail support, add this to your functions.php file.

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

This will help your load times dramatically.

Comment: my theme has post-thumbnails support. But i'm not using it. Because post-thumbnails' aren't resizing automatically. There are a **Dynamic image resizer** box on *new post* page, i'm using it.

Comment: I would then have to agree with Jeremy that this should be taken up in the Woo Theme support forums.

Answer (score 1):

This function is marked as deprecated in source code and acts as wrapper for `woo_image()`.

- `woo_get_image()` accepts `return` as one of the arguments, which makes it return rather than echo result;
- `woo_image()` accepts array of arguments, one of which can be `return` with same function.